# Accessing the source of one tab in the extension's tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I need to get the source code of the Active Tab when the extension icon is clicked; it needs to be visible in a new tab (because a pop up is limited to 800px, among other reasons).

I had no issue with this when I was using a popup, however, I now want to get the data into a new tab.

What is happening is the **targetTab** variable used in the **onClicked** callback contains the correct tab information. However, once the new tab (popup.html) is opened, nothing occurs; the **document.body.innerHTML** does not get changed.

Any ideas?

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Stock Alert",
  "description": "Create an alert and display streaming stock quotes.",
  "version": "1.1",
  "permissions": [
    "https://www.gwm.ml.wallst.com/",
    "https://*/*",
    "http://*/*",
    "tabs",
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "logo.png"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(targetTab) {
  chrome.tabs.create({'url': chrome.extension.getURL('popup.html')}, function(tab)
  {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript( 
            targetTab.id,
            {
                code: "document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML;"
            }, 
            function (sourceCode)
            {
                document.getElementById('dump').innerHTML = sourceCode;
            });
  });
});
```

popup.html (misnomer; this is the url of the new tab created onClicked)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Stock Tracker</title>
<!--<script src="background.js"></script>-->
<link href="Streamer.css.package.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="out"></div>
<div id="dump"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the callback function is executed within the background page context. It will therefore try to find `<div id="dump"></div>` inside that page, rather than inside the popup page.

I've fiddled around, and I've came up with the following solution.

1. On click, get the content of the current page
2. Store that content in the background page
3. Load the popup.html
4. On load, get the code content from the background page

**background.js**

```
var myCode;

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(targetTab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript( 
    targetTab.id,
    {
        code: "document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML;"
    }, 
    function (sourceCode)
    {            
        myCode = sourceCode;
        chrome.tabs.create({'url': chrome.extension.getURL('popup.html')});
    });
});
```

**popup.html**

Add `<script src="popup.js"></script>`

**popup.js**

```
chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function(bg)
{
   document.getElementById('dump').innerHTML = bg.myCode;
});
```

Comment: This seems like it should work, however the `chrome.tabs.executeScript` function now appears to be breaking; `onClick` no longer does anything (no new tab). The rest of your solution works, including accessing the `myCode` variable from the external JS.

Comment: Fix: the `chrome.tabs.create` function needs to be outside of the `executeScript` function; in fact it should come before it.

Comment: If you call the `chrome.tabs.create` function outside and before the `executeScript`, then you're not guaranteed that the `myCode` variable will be initialised, since all `chrome.*` are asynchronous. I tested this code, and it worked for me, what error do you see?

Comment: It's true that `myCode` may not be initialized, however I'm running this function on a timer, so eventually `myCode` will have data. I saw no errors; but `onClick` no longer opened a new tab.